# How to convert user menu tabs to menu links?

Tags: users, routes

I have on user account 5-6 tabs created by some modules.My wish is to covert these tabs to menu items so as to insert to 2 separate menu links.
I have read that something like that could be possible with hook_menu_alter.
Is this correct?If so,how can I use it in my case?
thanks a lot

Comment: Your question is unclear, you have provided no examples and no information about the modules used to generate tabs. Are tabs li elements of the same menu? Tabs as menu items with 2 separate menu links? Links are under items, am I correct? So 5-6 tabs in 2 items or 2 menus?

Comment: Okay,the tabs are being created on the User account  by Hybrid auth module,Userpoints,Commerce credits,Commerce(Orders tab),Search api saved searches etc.I am interested in removing these tabs from user account page and instead place them as menu items in 2 menus,half of them to one menu and the other half to the other menu.I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: You will have to write a module to do all this stuff. Get all items from respective modules and aggregate them in two separate menus, publish them on the user page and unpublish tabs from your user pages. These menu items are probably dinamically generated, using tokens or abstract url links behind.

Comment: Shall I do this with hook_menu_alter?If yes,could you give me an example?thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By creating an extremely simple custom module, you can [Remove tabs using hook_menu_alter](https://www.drupal.org/node/483324). Make sure to also clear the cache when you experiment with this.

Note: Consider refining your question to specify the path of each of those tabs you want to replaced.

Comment: Great,thank you ,I will try with hook_menu_alter,if I have any questions I will post here.Thanks again

Comment: ok, I'll be curious to hear how it turned out ...

Comment: Hm I tried with hook_menu_alter,it doesn't remove the tab,instead it restricts access to the path.What am I missing?
The code is here 
function custom_menu_alter(&$items) {
$items['users/%user/hybridauth']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
}

Comment: Anyway,I think I will do this with the Tab tamer module